# apple-app-site-association never requested

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm using cordova-universal-links in a mobile app. They're working fine on the Android side, but nothing is happening on iOS. Here's a rundown of everything so far:

- It **is** being served over HTTPS
- It **is** valid JSON
- It **is not** behind any redirect
- The app's certificate **does** have Associated Domains enabled
- The app **does** have this domain in its `.entitlements` file
- The app **has not** ever been released yet

I'm not sure if Test Flight has anything to do with it, but from tailing server logs, the `apple-app-site-association` file is never requested. Not when installing the app, not when navigating to the page from a link in Safari, not when navigating to the page from a link in Mail.

I am at a complete loss here.

Some screenshots:

cURL showing `application/json` and non-redirect status:
[image]

`.entitlements` file in Xcode:
[image]

Associated Domains in Xcode:
[image]

Associated Domains enabled in Developer Center:
[image]

AASA Validator from Branch.io:
[image]

Comment: So I've gotten universal links working, sometimes. It seems only when developing, using XCode to push to device / simulator (the command-line `cordova run ios` doesn't seem to work). Unfortunately, even with the app released in the app store, it's not requesting `apple-app-site-association`, and universal links aren't working.

Comment: Is it working now? I am facing same issue.